# If there is a blank field on my application it crashes (java, android)

Tags: java, android

I have tried a few things that I searched here but they didn't work. I tried a try/catch method and many if-functions it's crazy. I basically just want to display a message in a text view box when nothing is entered to tell the user to enter something. This is basically just an application to display the average that person has run for a certain amount of km.

Here is my code below:

````
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Initiating and referencing for Calculate Button
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        //onClickListener for the Calculate Button
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //Variables to calculate average runtime
            final EditText totalHours   = findViewById(R.id.totalHours);
            final EditText totalMinutes = findViewById(R.id.totalMins);
            double kilometer = 42.2;
            //Creating a variable to display an error message
            final TextView errorMsg = findViewById(R.id.errorMsg);
            //Checking to see if anything was entered into the editText fields -- THE ISSUE I HAVE
            if(totalHours.length() < 0 || totalMinutes.length() < 0){
             errorMsg.setText(R.string.nothingEnteredError);
            } else {
                //Parse the input from the user (from text to double)
                double Hours = Integer.parseInt(totalHours.getText().toString());
                double Minutes = Integer.parseInt(totalMinutes.getText().toString());
                //Checking requirements - not more than 10 hours entered and not more than 59 minutes entered.
                if (Hours > 10) {
                    errorMsg.setText(R.string.errorOnHours);
                } else if (Minutes > 59) {
                    errorMsg.setText(R.string.errorOnMinutes);
                } else {
                    //calculating average runtime
                    double average = ((Hours * 60) + Minutes) / kilometer;
                    //setting the format to 0.00
                    DecimalFormat aForm = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                    //creating a string version of average
                    String sAverage = Double.toString(average);
                    //Text to display in the second activity
                    String textToSet = String.format("Your average time to run one kilometer was %s", aForm.format(average));
                    //creating net intent to start the results page activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, resultsPage.class);
                    //adding textToSet to the results activity
                    i.putExtra("key", textToSet);
                    i.putExtra("average", sAverage);
                    //Starting results activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: you haven't really indicated where the problem occurs, but regardless, there are loads of posts available to explain how to resolve nullpointers, app crashes, empty strings, etc, it would be better if you showed specifically what's causing an issue and what isn't working

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
totalHours.length() < 0 || totalMinutes.length() < 0
```

Here you only check if the length is lower than zero.
I would try changing this so it checks for `length <= 0`

Comment: @Vexdee You can accept the answer to say thank you without disturbance. Pls delete that comment and accept his answer if it was useful to you.